# Why am I having problems opening windows programmatically?

Tags: javascript

I have an application where I want a button to open three different calendars in separate windows.  The button has an action which references he following JS function:

```
 function all_calendars() {
    var target = "www.calendar_a.com";
    var title = "Calendar A";
    window.open(target, title, '_new');

    var target = "www.calendar_b.com";
    var title = "Calendar B";
    window.open(target, title, '_new');

    var target = "www.calendar_c.com";
    var title = "Calendar C";
    window.open(target, title, '_new');

}
```

Only the third calendar opens and in a new tab.  I would prefer three windows, though I gather that is a browser setting, but why does only one of them open?

Comment: Why do you use `_new` as third argument?

Comment: The browser is probably complaining about it and only opens one.

Comment: OK, I feel foolish.  _clear is not a good substitute for _blank which works just fine.  I get three tabs.

Comment: Is the only way to get multiple windows to change the browser default?

Answer (score 1):

MDC states in [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) about open method

> The name should not contain any blank space

Hence, you're opening all in the same "Calendar" window.